# Is there a way to verify a table with rules against a log table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a beginner with oracle and I would like to know how to solve the below issue (I also like to learn so would like it to get a bit of an explanation for the solution).

I've two tables one contains rules and the other one contains the logs. Now I want to be able to check which rule is used for an entry in the log. This way I want to check if all rules are still valid or should be updated.

First table: t_logon_log

```
username  os_user program terminal hostname ip_address logon_time
username1 user1   unknown unknown  server1  1.2.3.4    12-09-19
username1 user2   unknown unknown  server2  2.3.4.5    19-09-19
username1 user3   unknown unknown  server3  3.4.5.6    19-10-19
```

Second table: t_allowed_connections

```
rule# username  os_user program hostname ip_address apply_rule
60    username1 user2   *       *        *          Yes
8     username1 *       *       *        *          Yes
```

Now I've created a query, which simply groups the log table together so I can manually review it.

```
select      Count(*), USERNAME, OS_USER, PROGRAM, TERMINAL, HOSTNAME, IP_ADDRESS
from        t_logon_log
where       LOGON_TIME > '01-01-19'
group by    USERNAME, OS_USER, PROGRAM, TERMINAL, HOSTNAME, IP_ADDRESS
order by    USERNAME;
```

But I would like to create a query which delivers an output which gives me back for each row from the query above which rule# number is valid for that row.

With this I want to compare the result to the rules and see which ones can be deleted on made more strictly.

Comment: Please explain the logic for matching "rules" to log rows.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that `'*'` means "match any value".  Otherwise the rules need to match the specific value.

So, you would use `join`, taking into account the wildcards:

```
select l.*,
       ac.rule_number
from t_logon_log l join
     t_allowed_connections ac
     on (ac.username = l.username or ac.username = '*') and
        (ac.os_user = l.os_user or ac.os_user = '*') and
        (ac.os_user = l.program or ac.program = '*') and
        (ac.os_user = l.hostname or ac.hostname = '*') and
        (ac.os_user = l.ip_address or ac.ip_address = '*') 
where ac.apply_rule = 'Yes';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `join` to find a matching rule for each connection.

```
select  *
from    t_logon_log l
left join
        t_allowed_connections r
on      (r.username = '*' or r.username = l.username) and
        (r.os_user = '*' or r.os_user = l.os_user) and
        (r.program = '*' or r.program = l.program) and
        ...
```

A `left join` repeats each matching row in the left hand table for each row in the right hand table.  If no rows match, a row consisting of `null` values is used.

Comment: Thank you, so in this case if the log row doesn't match any of the rows in t_allowed_connections the column behind will give a null value?

Comment: Yeah, it'll show with the rule columns as `null`. You can use `on r.apply_rule = 'Yes' and (r.username = '*' ...` to only consider applied rules